# How to enable Gitlab Coverage Check (Premium)

Tags: gitlab, test-coverage, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to enable the native Gitlab Coverage Check Approval rule. I've already configured my `gitlab-ci.yml` correctly with Jest Junit reporter. I've also enabled the feature on Gitlab project by following [these docs](https://git.pipefy.net/help/ci/pipelines/settings#coverage-check-approval-rule).

If you have Gitlab Premium you can turn on the Coverage-check feature by this path:

> `Settings > General > Merge Request Approvals > Coverage-Check`.

I can see all the artifacts but I'm not able to see the **Coverage Check Approval** box in the MR page.

I can see this box

[image]

But I can't see this box (Coverage Check Box)

[image]

Am I'm missing somthing?

Below my Approval rules configuration

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your approval rule configuration? Make sure the target branch matches, at least 1 approval is required, and at least 1 approver is added to the rule. Also make sure the latest pipeline on the target branch has a (non-expired) coverage report artifact.

Comment: Hey @sytech , I updated my question with screenshots of my rules.

Comment: Did the rule exist before opening the MR? If not, you may have to close the MR and open a new one. Also, if you're using self-hosted GitLab, there is a [known issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345386) that appears to have been fixed in GitLab 14.6 (although the issue is still open for some reason) -- otherwise, there's nothing apparent to me of why this isn't working as expected if you have non-expired coverage reports in the **target** branch.

Comment: This is not a question about programming.

Comment: It's a question about Software Engineering